# why form data is not passing to views.py?

Tags: python, django

**html form**

```
<form method="POST" action="/thanks">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email@something.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">What type of blog you need?</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**in views.py it prints nothing with if condition. Without if-condition, it prints none**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    print(name)
```

Comment: Do you access this view with a POST request? Have you made sure that the data is sent (browser dev tools, postman, ...)?

Comment: The action for the form is going to '/thanks'.  Is '/thanks' the correct URL for your views.py code?

Comment: Please include the Urls code too as it is a part of the whole issue.